# how can i get a gridview column number from the header row value

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a page where depending on whether a user is authenticated or not certain columns in a gridview do not display. In the row data bound event i need to determine the column number of the cells i need to apply formatting to based on their header text

I need to do something along the lines of what I show below.

```
If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            Dim revColumn As Integer = row."Headercelltext find it"
            row.Cells(revColumn).Text = String.Format("{0:c0}", Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(revColumn).Text))
        End If
```

Comment: Do your work on `Databound` event of gridview

Comment: it is in the databound event but how do you retrieve the column number using the text from the column header?

Comment: What do you mean by `Column No`? Can you elobrate

Comment: a gridview has columns in order to access a column, to code something like rows.Cells(4).Text =....   you need to be able to retrieve the column number, 4 in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

For Hiding Column based on `Role`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       GridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    }
```

And for formatting

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            if (Session["Role"] == "admin")
                btnVal.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

**Find Column Index by Column Text**

```
 private int GetColumnIndexByName(GridView grid, string name)
    {
        foreach (DataControlField col in grid.Columns)
        {
            if (col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim())
            {
                return grid.Columns.IndexOf(col);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```